# Rails 4 Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, namespaces

I am getting a routing error when I attempt to create a new db entry or update a current one.

ERROR: No route matches [POST] "/pubs"

Routes.rb:

```
resources :people, except: [:show] do
  resources :pubs, except: [:create, :new, :edit, :destroy]
end

resources :articles
resources :pubs, except: [:create, :new, :edit, :destroy]


namespace :sekret do
    resources :people do
      resources :pubs
    end
end
```

sekret/pubs_controller

```
class Sekret::PubsController < SekretController

def index
    @pubs = Pub.all
end

def show
    @pub = Pub.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
    @pub = @person.pubs.new
end

def create

    @pub = Pub.new(pub_params)

    if @pub.save
        flash[:notice] = "Article created successfully!"
        redirect_to sekret_person_pub_path(@pub)
    else
        render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def edit
    @pub = Pub.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @pub = Pub.find(params[:id])

    if @pub.update(pub_params)
        redirect_to sekret_person_pub_path(@pub)
    else
        render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def destroy
    pub = Pub.find(params[:id])
    pub.destroy
    redirect_to sekret_people_path
end




private
def pub_params
    params.require(:pub).permit(
        :pubmed_id, :journal, :pages, :date, :type, :link, :authors,
        :title, :notes, :auth_id, :person_id)
end
end
```

After going through all of this setup, when I allow the non-namespace pubs to resolve edit, update, etc, the update process goes through without a hitch. Once I limit these functions to within the password protected namespace I get the routing error. After parsing through the routes I can see that sekret_person_pub_path is listed there. I think I am missing something somewhere.

Rake Routes:

```
pubs#index
                            pub GET    /pubs/:id(.:format)                               pubs#show
                                PATCH  /pubs/:id(.:format)                               pubs#update
                                PUT    /pubs/:id(.:format)                               pubs#update
             sekret_person_pubs GET    /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs(.:format)          sekret/pubs#index
                                POST   /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs(.:format)          sekret/pubs#create
          new_sekret_person_pub GET    /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs/new(.:format)      sekret/pubs#new
         edit_sekret_person_pub GET    /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs/:id/edit(.:format) sekret/pubs#edit
              sekret_person_pub GET    /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs/:id(.:format)      sekret/pubs#show
                                PATCH  /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs/:id(.:format)      sekret/pubs#update
                                PUT    /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs/:id(.:format)      sekret/pubs#update
                                DELETE /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs/:id(.:format)      sekret/pubs#destroy
                  sekret_people GET    /sekret/people(.:format)
```

Comment: What do you see when you ```rake routes```?

Comment: Added the routes to the original post. Since I am new to all of this, if the route is: /sekret/people/:person_id/pubs/:id(.:format)   Do I have to find a way to put the :person_id and :id in there or will it generate based off of the page it is updating from?

Answer (score 0):

By using `resources :pubs, except: [:create, :new, :edit, :destroy]`, you are preventing the route generation from providing `POST /pubs`.

The `namespace` and nested `resources` will generate a URL `POST sekret/people/:person_id/pubs`.

In your controller, you should create the Pub as an associated object.

```
def create
  person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
  @pub = person.pubs.new(pub_params)

  if @pub.save
    flash[:notice] = "Article created successfully!"
    redirect_to sekret_person_pub_path(@pub)
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

If you want to restrict access the `create` method, you could use an authorization library such as Pundit in which case you would setup a policy to restrict who can do what.

https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out on the routes because rails form don't use the correct routes when namespacing so you'll have to specify them manually

```
<%= form for @pub, url: sekret_person_pubs_path do |f| %>
```

to let the form knows which route to post, if you do not specify the url, rails will use `url: person_pubs_path` behind the scenes

Edit: forgot to add _path

Comment: How does this work if I am using a from partial? The page calls the stub with: <%= render 'form', pub: @pub %>.  Or would it replace the stub opener <%= form_for(pub) do |f| %>>?

Comment: You can just do it inside the form partial, (pub, url: sekret_person_pubs_path) do |f|